# Gradle project doesn't build on my machine, but does on everyone else's

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm trying to start some work on a Gradle project, but I get a strange error when attempting to build the project on my machine. Currently, we have a Gradle project that builds successfully for all other members of my team, all they need to do is clone the project and it builds without any problems. For myself, that isn't the case.

If I execute the gradle wrapper manually from the terminal:

```
    ./gradlew build
```

the project builds without any errors, but the Gradle synchronisation fails when importing the project into an IDE, giving the following error:

```
    * What went wrong:
    Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':billing- 
    provisioning-consumer-finance-details:compile'
```

I assume that it can't be a problem with the project structure, nor anything wrong with the build.gradle, since it builds without error on other machines.

So far I've tried:

- Re-cloning the project (several times)
- Clearing the gradle cache at ~/.gradle/caches
- Clearing ~/.m2/repositories
- Building the project in another IDE (Eclipse), which still gives the same error.

Comment: Could you try with `--stacktrace` ?

Comment: Do you use a local shared repository? Looks like you are working on a *nix like box - you can check whether your /etc/hosts has same entries as other machines where build is successful?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps :

1. Download Gradle from [Gradle](https://gradle.org/releases/)
2. Create or Export **GRADLE_HOME** as environment variable.Ex: **E:\SoftwareRepo\building tools\gradle-4.4.1**
3. Add to Path or Export Path Variable PATH=[YOUR GRADLE_HOME/bin] . ex. **E:\SoftwareRepo\building tools\gradle-4.4.1\bin**
4. Open cmd or terminal anywhere in your PC and run  **gradle --v** . If gradle install successfully it will show installed gradle info.
5. Clone your gradle project
6. Go to project root directory. Open terminal and run **gradle clean build**

If there is still error then it will be probably your project is not correctly configured.

If you tried with intelij idea then you need to try this

1. **File->Open**. then select your source folder.
2. then a popup will come select local destribution gradle
   [image: Local destribution]

Comment: Thanks, I've installed Gradle locally as you suggested and it built successfully without any errors. Only having errors when running the build in Eclipse or Intellij!

Comment: please again check description. I just updated some IDE related part

Comment: Thanks again, tried using the local gradle version as you suggested and it's still failing with the same error.